# Struggling with dlib, linker errors and save_jpeg in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, libjpeg, dlib

First, I am new to C++ and dlib but I have successfully built the examples and started working on my own project. Things have been progressing smoothly until I try to save a jpeg. Attempting to compile code using `dlib::save_jpeg` throws a linker error and I cannot track down the solution. I have attempted to add `#define DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT` above and below my `#include`s but no luck. I am using XCode and used `cmake -G "Xcode" ..` when I compiled the examples. Relevant code below. Since I am on a Mac, I have added header and library search paths for X11 (for dlib gui), OpenCV, and DLIB. I have libjpeg.dylib and linked that to my project with and without `#define DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT` in `main.cpp`. Is there some other build setting I need to specify? Thank you in advance for your help.

Finally, I have seen other questions and pages about dlib and libjpeg issues but no luck yet. And yes I have source.cpp included in the project.

```
// the standard stuff
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

// opencv mat object
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

// dlib>
#include <dlib/opencv.h>
#include <dlib/image_io.h>
#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>
#include <dlib/image_transforms.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    // retrieving images from a TCP connection

    // decode data stream
    img = cv::imdecode(rawImage, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    // perform image processing    

    dlib::cv_image<dlib::bgr_pixel> d_image(img);

    // finally save the result to jpg
    std::string fname = argv[1] + std::to_string(image_id) + ".jpg";
    dlib::save_jpeg(d_image, fname); // <- line that won't compile
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After quit a bit of struggling and side-by-side comparisons I finally found the issue. In XCode go to to `Build Settings` and modify `Other Linker Flags`, `Run Search Paths`, and `Other C++ Flags` to match the compiled and working `face_ex` example. I wholesale copied all of those flags and included a missing `libjpeg.dylib` and was able to get things running. It should look something like this for the C++ flags [image]. Hope this helps the next person.

Comment: You could also use cmake to generate the project. Then it would have worked immediately.